# Crystal Reports Dynamic Groupings

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new in crystal reports so I don't know what to do

How can I make a group with this formula: 
in Main Report

```
if DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})=1 then
//group by
PROD.GROUP_ID
else if DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})>1 and 
   ({PROD.GROUP_ID}=previous({PROD.GROUP_ID}) or 
   {PROD.GROUP_ID}=next({PROD.GROUP_ID})) then
//group by 
    PROD.DOC_ID
else
//group by 
    PROD.GROUP_ID
```

Please help me with this I am new in crystal reports and I need to make this badly

I have this in my main report: 
in the group header and it is group by {PROD.GROUP_ID} 
Sub_Car 
Sub_Airplane

Some of my sub reports are working when it is group by {PROD.GROUP_ID} and some sub reports works when this is group by {PROD.DOC_ID}

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to group the result of the grouping to regroup which is not possbile by the way you wrote the formula because `DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})` is itself the output of the grouping.

To achive this you need to use the sub report and pass the distinct count to use as grouping in sub report.

Take another section `group footer b` and place the sub report there and using `Change sub report links` pass the `DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})` to the sub report

in sub report it will be appearing in parameter fields as `{?DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})}` now create your formula as `@grouping` and write below code:

```
if {?DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})}=1 then
//group by
PROD.GROUP_ID
else if {?DistinctCount ({PROD.GROUP_ID}, {PROD.ID_NO})}>1 and 
   ({PROD.GROUP_ID}=previous({PROD.GROUP_ID}) or 
   {PROD.GROUP_ID}=next({PROD.GROUP_ID})) then
//group by PROD.DOC_ID
else
//group by PROD.GROUP_ID
```

Now use the formula to group the sub report... if you wish display data in main report or remove all fields of main report and just show sub report

Comment: The @grouping formula is not showing in change group. sorry for another problem but why is that?

Comment: if would show up for that you need to use the fields in report... place the fields on report and try using the formula

Comment: why it still can't find the @grouping in change group I had put it in the sub report. When I direct the formula in Group name formula editor it says "This function cannot be used because it must be evaluated first"

Comment: Where did you place the sub report..first main report should be evaluated then value should be passed to sub report

Comment: I had place my sub report in the group footer

Comment: Before or after the distict count...can you post screenshot of design

Comment: I had made a more detailed question from other topic which will further explain what I wanted to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939108/crystal-reports-merge-duplicate-columns-same-data