# Crystal reports merge duplicate columns same data

Tags: merge, crystal-reports

Is there a formula for this:

```
mainId    productId   groupId    product       price        qty
456         123        555         book          10          2
456         789        555         book          10          2
222         125        888         pencil        20          5         
222         125        859         pencil        20          1
```

it shows (from sub report to main report):

```
product: book
Computation: 10x2     20

product: book
Computation: 10x2     20

Total                 40
```

I want the result to be like this if data produce are the same like the one above:

```
product: book
Computation: 10x4     40

Total                 40
```

if not the same data like with the mainId 222 the result should be like this:

```
product: pencil
Computation: 20x5     100

product: pencil
Computation: 20x1     20

Total                120
```

In sub report I group it by productId

```
Group Header: [Group#1 Name]
Details:
Group Footer: [product]
Computation:  [computation (10x2)]   [total (20)]
```

In main report I group it by productId too. I group the Subreport in Group Header. In the Page Footer is the Grand Total which is 20.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you should group on GroupID rather than productid?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: You still working on this issue 6 years later?

Comment: I came across this page and viewed a post that isn't clear, so I left a comment. If this is supposed to be an answer, I recommend editing it so that it contains an expository statement rather than an interrogative statement; answer posts are not for asking questions.